# Subroute with Variable Name in ReactJS Router

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I'm a reactjs newbie, trying to figure out routing.

I'm using "react-router-dom" and I want to set up some links like this:

```
/p/<some id>
/p/<some id>/friends
/p/<some id>/pictures
/p/<some id>/otherstuff
```

With the below, I have the link "/p/<some id>" which maps to <Profile> working, but "/p/<some id>/friends" which maps to <Friends>, and subsequent subroutes. still resolve to <Profile>

I have the following:

```
root.render(
    <React.StrictMode>
        <BrowserRouter>
            <Routes>
                <Route path="/" element={<App />} >
                <Route path="/p/:someId" element={<Profile />} >
                    <Route path="friends" element={<Friends />} />
                    <Route path="pictures" element={<Pictures />} />
                    ....
                </Route>
            </Routes>
        </BrowserRoute>
     <React.StrictMode>
```

)

My App.js

```
function App() {
    return (
        <div className="App">
            <Outlet />
        </div>
    );
} 

export default App; // nothing special
```

and Friends.js

```
const Friends = () => {
    return(
        <div className="App">
            <h1>Friends</h1>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Friends; // again, nothing special (the rest of the components are pretty much the same)
```

How can I get the above links to work?

Thanks!

Comment: `Profile` component must also render `Outlet` beacause it contains other routes.

Comment: Please clarify what exactly the issue is, what precisely isn't working as expected. Just about anything is better than just saying "it not work". Are there any errors? What is the observed behavior versus the expected behavior? What debugging steps have you taken? What are the steps to reproduce the issue? Have you included all relevant code you've an issue working with and using in a [mcve]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Route nesting](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/getting-started/overview#nested-routes) not only nest the route paths, it also nest your components. Which means that for your route `/p/:someId/friends`, for example, your component tree will be:

```
<App>
  <Profile>
    <Friends />
  </Profile>
</App>
```

To render the nested routes, you need to add the [`<Outlet>`](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/components/outlet) component on `<Profile>` as well.